# c# stacking different classes in the same list

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

I'm learning inheritance and have a few questions:

- Assuming I have a base class A.
- Class `B` and class `C` are different classes that inherit from `A`.

  1. Assuming I want to stack in the same list instances of class `B` and `C`, 
     what is the type of the list should be?  `List<object>` or `List<A>` ?
  2. Why `List<A>` can hold the data of class `B` and `C` if Class `A` has fewer fields? I would expect that `List<A>` will trim the extra fields of class `B` and `C` inside the list, but I saw a working example of it.
  3. When looping the list with `foreach` how can I tell if the object is class `B` or `C`?

Thank you!

Comment: The point of inheritance is to reuse code. The point of polymorphism is to hide the implementation from the calling code by providing a common interface. So, if you are doing proper OOP ([SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles are a good starting point), then placing instances of different classes into the same list only makes sense if they share the same interface. For the caller, all the object in that list will be instances of `A`. If you need to check the type of the object inside the `foreach` loop, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: An Interface is your friend. Anyway, if you add a `B` or `C` class to a `List<A>` and check `List<A>[N] is B`, `List<A>[N] is C`, the test will return the actual class stored at that index. You can then cast to the right class (it may not be even necessary, depending on what you're doing with it).

Comment: 2. `class A` is a [Reference Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), hence only references are stored in that list (like a reference counting C++ pointer)

Answer (score 2):

1. The the type parameter of the list must be the nearest common ancestor of `B` and `C`: here `List<A>`. `List<object>` would also work, but at the cost that it is weakly typed and allows you add any kind of objects: strings integers, dates, persons. Which is probably not the intention here.
2. Class types are reference types. This means that the list only contains references to objects of different length, that are not themselves in the list. I.e. no truncation occurs. This is also the reason why value types can not be inherited. You cannot inherit from an `int` or from a struct like `DateTime`.
3. Let's imagine a better example for this question

```
public abstract class : Shape
{
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public double Radius { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let us calculate the total area of shapes in a list `List<shape> shapes`:

```
double totalArea = 0.0;
foreach (Shape shape in shapes) {
    if (shape is Rectangle rect) {
        totalArea += rect.Width * rect.Height;
    } else if (shape is Circle circle) {
        totalArea += circle.Radius * circle.Radius * Math.Pi;
    }
}
```

or

```
double totalArea = 0.0;
foreach (Shape shape in shapes) {
    switch (shape)
    {
        case Rectangle rect:
            totalArea += rect.Width * rect.Height;
            break;
        case Circle circle:
            totalArea += circle.Radius * circle.Radius * Math.Pi;
            break;
    }
}
```

But generally it is better if you don't need to know the type. E.g. Instead of using the `switch` in the last example, let the classes themselves do the job

```
public abstract class : Shape
{
    public abstract double Area { get; }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public override double Area => Width * Height;
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public double Radius { get; set; }

    public override double Area => Radius * Radius * Math.Pi;
}
```

Then the loop becomes

```
double totalArea = 0.0;
foreach (Shape shape in shapes) {
    totalArea += shape.Area;
}
```

This is called [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) (multi-shaped). In this case `shape` can be a `Rectangle` or a `Circle`. But you don't have to care. `shape.Area` will automatically call `Rectangle.Area` for `Rectangle` objects and `Circle.Area` for `Circle` objects. This is the true power of object orientation, where as the solutions with `if` or `switch` are a procedural approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers! Regarding question 3, you showed how we can access the same methode (differently implemented) of each class without the if or switch statment. But how to access specific properties that only class B and C are possessed?

Comment: You have two possibilities: 1. By using these if or switch. 2. By using these properties in common methods or other properties. E.g. If the base class is a `Shape` with two derived classes `Rectangle` with `Length` and `Width` properties and `Circle` with a `Radius`, then calculate the area in a common property `Area` instead of accessing the new properties from outside with if or switch.

Comment: I included a better example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its basic oop (object oriented proggreming) principall called polymorphisem

1. you shoud use list`List<A>`
2. when you put `B` type object into `List<A>` its like to look on B as A. so you can access th A fields that it inherits
3. you can use the `is` statement.
   for example  `if (someObject is B)`

you can reed more here [polymorphisem docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `List<A>`, you can use it for each class of the type of `A` and all derived classes. Lets take it to the real world:

If you have a definition `Vehicle` (that's your `A`). You could write a software for a car rental company which handles vehicles. They have all sorts for vehicles like one or more bikes (that's `B`) and one or more cars (that's `C`). Both are very different but both are vehicles.

By using the abstraction of a `Vehicle` (`A`), you can store bikes and cars in the same context.

So in a `List<Vehicle>`, you could store bikes, cars, trucks and all sort of movable stuff. However, the definition `Vehicle` will have the least common denominator like the kind of motor, the count of doors, etc. But you would (hopefully) not find truck-specific properties on that definition of vehicle which might not fit to others like a bike or a car.

Tracking bikes and cars as vehicles does not strip of the fields at all. However, they are treated as vehicles, that's why you would not see the specific properties until you cast each vehicle to its real type. There are some approaches to this, I'd like to highlight Pattern Matching in C# 7 which makes it really easy by now.

```
foreach (var v in vehicleList)
{
    switch (v)
    {
        case Bike b:
            // ... do bike specific things
            break;
        case Car c:
            // ... do car specific things
            break;
        case Truck t:
            // ... do truck specific things
            break;
        default:
            WriteLine("<unknown>");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pattern matching is neat, but OOP was invented precisely to avoid this type of code.

Comment: Good point, actually. I just wanted to show that the values are not lost if you recover the real type from the common vehicle list.

Comment: @Groo - "invented precisely to avoid this type of code" - What? No, it was invented to precisely allow this kind of code. Do you have a reference to avoiding it?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I am not sure what you are referring to with "precisely allow". Polymorphism means abstracting the actual object type and hiding the actual implementation through its interface (which is violated in this example which knows specifics of each subclass). Single responsibility principle states that a class should have single reason to change (violated here, you will need to update each `switch`/`case` in your program when you add a `Boat`). This code is basically the school example for [refactoring into OO code](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

Comment: @Groo - OOP wasn't invented with the SOLID principles. They came along later. OOP was invented to allow polymorphism. When I said "precisely allow" I was referring to your line "invented precisely to avoid this type of code".

Comment: The main selling point of OOP, as I see it, is abstracting your classes through a common interface. I can understand that pattern matching is idiomatic in functional languages such as F#, which will refuse to compile if you miss a case, but the example above in C# is basically a huge if/then/else clause over a "type code" (`if (type == bike) do_bike_stuff(); else if (type == car) do_car_stuff(); else ...`), which is, as I wrote, a school example of how not to program in OOP languages.

Comment: @Enigmativity: regarding "precisely allow", if I understood correctly, you are arguing that OOP was invented to *"precisely allow"* pattern matching over a type code? Because, 1) you can easily do a huge switch/case over a type code in C, FORTRAN or Pascal, 2) C++ and Java do not have pattern matching, and 3) C# just got this is version 7.

Comment: @Groo - No, you're arguing that OOP was invented to avoid pattern matching. That was your original statement. I'm taking that to apply to any situation where you inspect the type, perform a cast, and then use the type. If that's not what you meant then I apologise, but I'm not sure what you could have meant?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, the whole point of polymorphism is that code using the abstraction has no need to know about the specific implementation details of each derived type or what they're doing, and can instead act on the abstraction and have each instance perform the appropriate actions.  What you've shown is very much an anti-pattern and is indicative that there's one or more operations that belong on the base type that aren't there.